# Corona SDK: is it possible to change the frameIndex of an ImageRect after it is created?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working with Corona SDK and I want to know if It's possible to change the `frameIndex` of a `newImageRect` after it is created.

Something like:

```
local platform = display.newImageRect( platformsSheet, 1, 130, 20 )
....
platform.frameIndex = 2
```

Of course, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can delete and recreate the image.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, but you can use [object:toFront()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toFront.html) and [object:toBack()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toBack.html).